# How to make React Native's ScrollView initial zoom to not be 1?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I want to put content (multiple images vertically arranged) in a React Native ScrollView (iOS only for now, Android will come later) that is bigger than the phone's screen, and start zoomed out so that it is all visible at the same time.

Are there any good examples of using ScrollView.scrollResponderZoomTo in a componentDidMount call that zooms out to fit content in the screen, something like

```
<ScrollView
  style={{width: 500, height: 1000}}
  // + whatever other properties make this work required way
>
  <View style={{width: 2000, height: 5000}}>
    <Image style={{width: 2000, height: 2000}} source={.....}/>
    <Image style={{width: 2000, height: 3000}} source={.....}/>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

I tried setting the 'zoomScale' property, but that seems to be ignored and always uses the value 1.

According to this issue (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2176) there is a scrollResponderZoomTo function that can be used, but when I try to use it, it seems that no matter what values I give it it zooms out much too far and off center.

The F8 sample app has a ZoomableImage module (https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/b5df451259897d1838933f01ad4596784325c2ad/js/tabs/maps/ZoomableImage.js) which uses the Image.resizeMode.contain style to make an image fit the screen, but that loses the quality of image, so when you zoom in it gets blurry.

Comment: I can confirm that setting the zoomScale property at declaration has no effect.

Comment: scrollResponderZoomTo function behaves as "no matter what values I give it it zooms out much too far and off center" in my case also.

Comment: Shane, I see you are listed as an Engineer at Facebook? Is it possible to ask your internal React Native team/group/mailing-list the correct way to go about doing this? (And if you did, I'd love it if you could share the answer externally here, as I have the exact same issue/interest!)

Comment: @Shane would you mind accepting my answer or telling me what fields I should cover?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may not be the way you intended to do this, but a possible solution:

You may get the devices height and width (`var {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window')`) and you know your image sizes,so you may easily calculate the needed width and height, let's call them `var neededWidth, neededHeight;`. You may then calculate the zoom to which you would like to zoom out: `var zoom = Math.min(height / neededHeight, width / neededWidth);`.

With these values in place, you may set an [Animated](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/animated.html#animated) value for the zoom, starting at 1 ending at `zoom` like this in your `componentWillMount`:

```
Animated.timing(
   this.state.animatedZoom,
   {toValue: zoom}
 ).start();
```

The constructor would look like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    animatedZoom: new Animated.Value(1),
  };
}
```

The render function would look like this (reference for transform can be found [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.27/docs/transforms.html#transforms)):

```
<ScrollView
  style={{width: 500, height: 1000, transform: [{ scale: this.state.animatedZoom }]}}
>
  <View style={{width: 2000, height: 5000}}>
    <Image style={{width: 2000, height: 2000}} source={.....}/>
    <Image style={{width: 2000, height: 3000}} source={.....}/>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: So making something zoomed-out to show everything all-at-once can use a transform scale, like you said. However, the questioner and I (the one volunteering the bounty) want to use the `ScrollView`'s zoom-in-and-out functionality (which is supported on iOS), and so want to use `zoomScale` (or something that sets it, like `scrollResponderZoomTo`), and plays nicely. Unfortunately, AFAICT a transform scale doesn't use the native `zoomScale`, and so would not play well with pinch-to-zoom and the like. (Perhaps I'm wrong on this assumption?)

Comment: That is right. I just wanted to show an alternative solution, not tied to the Scroll View. As the asker mentioned the ScrollView zoom option didn't work the right way, I thought it might be better to use such a generic solution. As you mention pinch-to-zoom: You may implement it with the Guesture Responder System.

Comment: @MikeLambert did you figure out how to accomplish what you describe above? I'm struggling as zoomScale doesn't seem to have any effect and I can't really find any helpful resources.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to control the zoom programatically. Let's say you want to set the default zoom level when the scrollview mounts. You can use the method `scrollResponderZoomTo` of the ScrollView's scroll responder with a timeout.

```
setScrollViewRef = (ref) => {
  this.mapScrollView = ref;
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.mapScrollView._scrollResponder.scrollResponderZoomTo({
      height: this.mapSize, width: this.mapSize, animated: false,
    });
  }, 1);
};
```

And render your scrollview with a `contentContainerStyle` constraining the size you want.

```
renderMapView = () => {
  this.mapSize = Dimensions.get('window').width * 2;
  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      ref={this.setScrollViewRef}
      maximumZoomScale={4}
      minimumZoomScale={0.5}
      contentContainerStyle={{ width: this.mapSize, height: this.mapSize }}
      centerContent
    >
      <Map width={this.mapSize} height={this.mapSize} />
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

This will set the default zoom level to 50% and let the whole `<Map />` be visible. If you want another zoom level, you can provide a different height/width to `scrollResponderZoomTo`. Only works on iOS.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work without some modification. `ref.scrollResponderZoomTo({ height: sheetStyle.height, width: sheetStyle.width, animated: false })`

Additionally, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

[@Levalis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57462521/4177374) save my day.

`scrollResponderZoomTo` is currently the best shot in React Native according to this issue [#2176](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2176)

If anyone encounter the "zooms out much too far and off center" problem, try to call `scrollResponderZoomTo` with the same rect as you set in your style:

```js
// declare image size in styles.js...
image: {
  width: <image width>,
  height: <image height>
}

// ...and inside your component
this.scrollView._scrollResponder.scrollResponderZoomTo({
  height: <image height>, width: <image width>, animated: false,
})
```